# CURRENCY ADJUSTED RETURNS: How to adjust stock returns in foreign currency (e.g., EUR) to local currency (USD)?

Tags: equities, finance, portfolio-management, returns, currency

I have collected monthly stock returns (in %) denominated in EUR and exchange rate EUR/USD.

I am trying to adjust the monthly stock returns denominated in EUR to monthly stock returns denominated in USD.

How do I calculate the currency adjusted returns?

So far I have calculated the monthly change in the exchange rate, then I have multiplied the change in the currency by the EUR return.

Comment: I think that was asked [before](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/33709/54838).

Comment: It is not completely the same question. The question that you refer to concerns how to convert closing prices into another currency. I am trying to adjust return data (in %) in one currency into another currency. :-)

Comment: "I have collected monthly stock returns (in %) denominated in EUR and exchange rate USD/EUR" - step 1, is the data synchronous?

Comment: @user42108, yes - data is synchronous.

Comment: @oliver: if you convert a EUR based Wealth Index into USD and then compute the percent changes in the latter, that gives you the USD returns. The answer by AKdemy below proves this result and gives you the explicit formulas (res1 and res2, which are equal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [link](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33702/converting-international-equity-returns-to-usd/33709#33709) is insufficient, does [this](https://www.investmentfrontier.com/2017/06/19/calculate-currency-adjusted-returns/) work?

[image]